# Why doesn't my TypeScript interface alert me that it is missing some properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have a TypeScript interface with required properties.

But when typing an object and pushing it into an array there is no error message alerting me that some of the required properties are missing.

Here is an example from my code:

```TypeScript
interface Keyword {
  keyword: string;
  language: string;
  location: string;
  searchEngineDomain: string;
  organicPositionLastThirtyDays: number[];
  createdAt: string;
}

const keywords = [];
keywords.push({
    keyword: 'My First Keyword',
} as Keyword);
```

I was expecting to see an error telling me the object I am pushing into the array is missing five required properties. But I see no error at all.

Why does this happen?

Comment: `as Keyword` is specifically the way to tell the compiler *not* to give you an error message about the fact that something is not of type `Keyword`. (Though in this context it would not give such an error message anyway since you didn't tell it the array should only have things of type `Keyword` in it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `keywords` is of type `any[]`, while it should be `Keyword[]`. You should also remove `as Keyword` as it kinda means "believe me, it's all we want here". Type assertions can hide type errors.

Check out the following snippet:

```
interface Keyword {
  keyword: string;
  language: string;
  location: string;
  searchEngineDomain: string;
  organicPositionLastThirtyDays: number[];
  createdAt: string;
}

const keywords: Keyword[] = [];
keywords.push({
    keyword: 'My First Keyword',
});
```

You will receive the following error:

> Argument of type '{ keyword: string; }' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'Keyword'.   Type '{ keyword: string; }' is missing the
> following properties from type 'Keyword': language, location,
> searchEngineDomain, organicPositionLastThirtyDays, createdAt